# Is there a way to run OpenBravo on AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine, open-source, openbravo

OpenBravo is an open source ERP system, is it possible to run it on Google's Java AppEngine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the app itself would run but the major obstacle is the relational database Openbravo comes with.

It supports Postgres and Oracle and due to the fact that A LOT of its business logic is inside stored procedures and triggers, it would require substantial effort to convert it to use app engine's datastore.

So the answer is no, not without a lot of work.